# Cannot install Sql Server 2019 on Windows Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, sql-server-2019

On a brand new install of Windows Server 2022 standard, I am trying to install SQL Server 2019.

I downloaded the eval version, put my key in and proceeded to install the Database Engine. Default instance. Tried both mixed and windows auth.

I have tried many of the different service accounts.
[image]

- Default
- NT Authority\SYSTEM
- NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
- NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

At the end of the install, I still get the same error: "Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed".

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Setup
------------------------------

The following error has occurred:

Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%25400x4BDAF9BA%25401306%254026

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image]
[image]

Each time I have tried uninstalling SQL Server, reinstalled and tried another account type. I have also tried setting the account no the SQL Server process itself to different account types but nothing is working. I have tried everything listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538089/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-check-the-sql-server-error-l) too but nothing gets the installer to succeed.

Is anyone else able to install SQL Server 2019 on Windows Server 2022? It should be supported but this is crazy that it won't install.

There is literally nothing else installed on this machine.

Some logs:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893606
  Start time:                    2021-10-14 12:00:52
  End time:                      2021-10-14 12:13:30
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  WEB02
  Machine processor count:       32
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard (10.0.20348)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2019 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2019
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       15
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\SQL2019\Evaluation_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

Notice: A paid SQL Server edition product key has been provided for the current action - Standard. Please ensure you are entitled to this SQL Server edition with proper licensing in place for the product key (edition) supplied.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20211014_120026\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             F:\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLJAVADIR:                    <empty>
  SQLMAXDOP:                     8
  SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647
  SQLMINMEMORY:                  0
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           WEB02\Administrator
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20211014_120026\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures or warnings:

Global rules:
Warning    IsFirewallEnabled                The Windows Firewall is enabled. Make sure the appropriate ports are open to enable remote access. See the rules documentation at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2094702 for information about ports to open for each feature.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20211014_120026\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

```
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
    Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2022 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 20348: )

2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      UTC adjustment: 2:00
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      All rights reserved.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Server process ID is 2872.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      System Manufacturer: 'ASUS', System Model: 'System Product Name'.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "MSSQLSERVER"
     -m "SqlSetup"
     -Q
     -q "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
     -T 4022
     -T 4010
     -T 3659
     -T 3610
     -T 8015
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 16 cores per socket and 32 logical processors per socket, 32 total logical processors; using 32 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Detected 130982 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.01 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.16 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 33554432 bytes for 20957208 hashPages.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.40 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2021-10-14 12:08:14.40 Server      Automatic soft-NUMA was enabled because SQL Server has detected hardware NUMA nodes with greater than 8 physical cores.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.42 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.43 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.44 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2021-10-14 12:08:14.44 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2021-10-14 12:08:14.44 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 8512 at 10/14/2021 12:08:11 PM (local) 10/14/2021 10:08:11 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.45 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000055555555:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000055555555:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.45 Server      Node configuration: node 1: CPU mask: 0x00000000aaaaaaaa:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000aaaaaaaa:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.49 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.49 Server      Lock partitioning is enabled.  This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.50 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on standard machine.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.50 Server      [INFO] Created Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'

2021-10-14 12:08:14.50 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.50 Server      Total Log Writer threads: 4. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.53 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.53 Server      clwb is selected for pmem flush operation.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.53 spid12s     Warning ******************
2021-10-14 12:08:14.53 spid12s     SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.54 spid12s     Starting up database 'master'.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.55 spid12s     There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO.  The current IO is on file F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.56 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2021-10-14 12:08:14.65 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
```

C: (where SQL is installed)
[image]

F: (where the data and log files are set to go)
[image]

Detail.txt (https://pastebin.com/3YGx1Dtn) from: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20211023_000906

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130698/discussion-on-question-by-dylan-cannot-install-sql-server-2019-on-windows-server).

Answer (score 2):

This is a new issue by installing SQL server on either windows 11 or windows server 2022.

SQL server require a correct value of storage drive sector size, both logical and physical and it seems this is main issue on windows 11 and windows server 2022 on new generation drives like M ssd.

Solution:
Install sql server on another drive, like an external drive

Update: Better solution

just use a virtual drive (VHD) for sql databases, not sql itself

Comment: I have Veeam which uses SQL LocalDB.  I cannot control where it puts its database.  I tried running the Veeam service as another user and putting that user profile on a different disk but Windows doesn't like that and keeps making C:\Users\Temp folders instead between reboots.

Comment: @Arrow_Raider, for an existing LocalDb installation, specify trace flag 1800 as detailed in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303823/error-starting-localdb-on-windows-11/303824#303824) as a workaround. Once can also install SQL on a VHD drive as a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, which is documented here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

The document only mentions Windows 11, but the issue also occurs on Windows Server 2022, and the same workaround(s) apply.

---

In a nutshell:

- Modern SSDs have a "sector size" larger than 4096 bytes.
- Some software products (such as SQL Server) don't support such a large sector size. Thus, Windows 10 and Windows Server before 2022 "emulated" a sector size of 4096 on those modern drives.
- This emulation is off by default in Windows 11/Server 2022.

The following command line can tell you if you are affected by this issue (replace `C:` with the drive containing your SQL Server DB files):

```
fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo C:
```

On affected systems, the value for `PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity` is larger than `4096`.

The easiest way to fix this is to turn the emulation layer back on, which can be done by setting a registry key with the following command line:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "* 4095" /f
```

After a reboot (didn't test whether it is really necessary), SQL Server 2019 installed successfully on my Windows Server 2022 system.